# What is the difference in placement of variables to right or left of equal sign during variable assignment.

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, file-io

To be honest I don't know how to ask this question well because I don't know the proper name for this kind of operation.
Basically, whats the difference between
This

```
string SavedWorkingDirectory;

SavedWorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
```

And this

```
string SavedWorkingDirectory;

Environment.CurrentDirectory = SavedWorkingDirectory;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Saves the contents of `Environment.CurrentDirectory` into `SavedWorkingDirectory`
2. Overwrites `Environment.CurrentDirectory`  with `SavedWorkingDirectory` which is `null` in your example

Answer (score 0):

The values on the right-side of the equal sign are assigned to the left-side.
The `=` in `a = b` is called an assignment operator, which assigns `b` to `a`